# How to make .toggle() work on responsive tabs to accordion

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cmscss/ou7rzj85/

It uses a definition list to create tabs that switch to an accordion on smaller viewport sizes. Everything is working except that I need to get an open accordion to close when it's clicked.

I thought that a simple toggle would work like this:

```
$(this).next().toggle().prev().toggleClass('active');
```

My understanding is that jQuery is going to the next item (the `<dd>`) and toggling visibility, then going to the previous item (the `<dt>`) and toggling the `.active` class.

The toggling of the `.active` class on the `<dt>` is working but the visibility toggling isn't - it only toggles on, not off.

Initially, I also tried a simpler version but saw the same issue:

```
$(this).toggleClass('active').next().toggle();
```

I'm sure it's easy and have just got my wires crossed somewhere - any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle is calling the following line first:

```
$('.accordion-content').hide(); // hide all content
```

Thus, when the `.toggle` is called, the content will be hidden, so it will always change it to visible. If you change the line to:

```
$('.accordion-content').not($(this).next()) //exclude current content
                       .hide(); // hide all other content
```

It should work as expected. See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ou7rzj85/1/

Comment: Of course! I couldn't get your code to work in my test page but I commented out the first 'hide all' line and that's all I need. Thank you so much for your help - simple when you know how. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

this example seems to have it working http://jsfiddle.net/cam/aff4vL5g/

```
$(function () {
    //  Accordion Panels
    $(".accordion div").show();
    setTimeout("$('.accordion div').slideToggle('slow');", 1000);
    $(".accordion h3").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".pane").slideToggle("slow").siblings(".pane:visible").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("current");
        $(this).siblings("h3").removeClass("current");
    });
});
```